# Nginx reverse proxy to https not working

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, lets-encrypt, gunicorn

I am trying to run more than one python/gunicorn api over https using nginx as a reverse proxy for my subdomain subdomain.domain.com. Below is my server block file subdomain.domain.com in sites-enabled.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;

    location /api/ {
           proxy_set_header HOST $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_pass http://localhost:6000;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }


    }

server {

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
server_name subdomain.domain.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
add_header Strict-Transport-Security “max-age=31536000”;

location / {
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }

location /api/ {
           proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host      $host;

           proxy_pass http://localhost:6000;
    }

}
```

Both endpoints are working over http but for not https. Port 443 is open on my server.

`curl -i https://subdomain.domain.com` times out. So I suspect it is a problem with certbot.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"... times out"* suggests a firewall blocking the traffic - which might be on the server but also somewhere in the path between client and server. certbot is unrelated to this, i.e. it will not cause a timeout of the connection.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please don't edit your solution into your question. Instead, post an answer and accept it. Otherwise the question will stay as "unanswered" in the system and pop up again and again in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steffen was correct port 443 was open in IPTABLES but not on default hetzner firewall. Thank you very much